# isolated singularities

Tags: complex-analysis

Here is the question I need your help.

let f be an entire function that satisfies lim|f(z)| goes to infinity as |z| goes to infinity. Prove that f is a polynomial.

Even though i could not come with a solid idea about solution so far but i thought first g(z)=1/f(z) then this makes g(z) entire and bounded by Liouville Th. g constant then f also constant. but this is not what we are looking for. then I came with the type of singularity g(z)=f(1/z) at 0. since f is an entire then we can write f(z)= Σ an z^n and g(z)=f(1/z)=Σ an (1/z)^n so there is an essential singularity at z=0 and that means f(z) has essential singularity at infinity. can you please correct me and help to complete my solution.

thanks.

Comment: $\frac{1}{f(z)}$ is only entire if $f$ has no zeros.

Comment: Dear ruud, Can you see how to show that $f$ has finitely many zeroes?  Once you do this, how about you try taking into account @DanielFischer's comment, and first remove the zeroes of $f$ by dividing $f$ through by an appropriate polynomial.  *Now* you have an entire function that has no zeroes, and you can try your $1/f(z)$ idea.   Regards,

Comment: Thanks everyone i guess i get that.

Answer (score 1):

Your hypothesis implies  that $f$ extends to a continuous map $\widehat f: \mathbb P^1(\mathbb C) \to \mathbb P^1 (\mathbb C)$ on  the projective line (aka the Riemann sphere  ) by defining $\widehat f(\infty)=\infty$ .
The extension is actually holomorphic by Riemann's extension theorem.
But then we know that all such holomorphic maps are rational functions and since in our case that rational function has no pole on $\mathbb C$, it is a polynomial.

**Remark**
The *conoscenti* will recognize  the simplest case of the  [GAGA principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_geometry_and_analytic_geometry#GAGA) in full action.